# JavaScript: Given an offset and substring length in an HTML string, what is the parent node?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

My current project requires locating an array of strings within an element's text content, then wrapping those matching strings in `<a>` elements using JavaScript (requirements simplified here for clarity). I need to avoid jQuery if at all possible - at least including the full library.

For example, given this block of HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>This is a paragraph of text used as an example in this Stack Overflow
     question.</p>
</div>
```

and this array of strings to match:

```
['paragraph', 'example']
```

I would need to arrive at this:

```
<div>
  <p>This is a <a href="http://www.example.com/">paragraph</a> of text used
     as an <a href="http://www.example.com/">example</a> in this Stack
     Overflow question.</p>
</div>
```

I've arrived at a solution to this by using the `innerHTML()` method and some string manipulation - basically using the offsets (via `indexOf()`) and lengths of the strings in the array to break the HTML string apart at the appropriate character offsets and insert `<a href="http://www.example.com/">` and `</a>` tags where needed.

However, an additional requirement has me stumped. I'm not allowed to wrap any matched strings in `<a>` elements if they're already in one, or if they're a descendant of a heading element (`<h1>` to `<h6>`).

So, given the same array of strings above and this block of HTML (the term matching has to be case-insensitive, by the way):

```
<div>
  <h1>Example</a>
  <p>This is a <a href="http://www.example.com/">paragraph of text</a> used
     as an example in this Stack Overflow question.</p>
</div>
```

I would need to disregard both the occurrence of "Example" in the `<h1>` element, and the "paragraph" in `<a href="http://www.example.com/">paragraph of text</a>`.

This suggests to me that I have to determine which node each matched string is in, and then traverse its ancestors until I hit `<body>`, checking to see if I encounter a `<a>` or `<h_>` node along the way.

Firstly, does this sound reasonable? Is there a simpler or more obvious approach that I've failed to consider? It doesn't seem like regular expressions or another string-based comparison to find bounding tags would be robust - I'm thinking of issues like self-closing elements, irregularly nested tags, etc. There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Secondly, is this possible, and if so, how would I approach it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably iterate the dom elements.  Here's a simple recursive dom iterator, you can fill in the rest:

```
function iterateDom (node) {
switch (node.nodeType) {
    case 1: // ELEMENT_NODE
        {
        if (node.tagName != "H1") {
            for (var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++)
                    iterateDom(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3: //TEXT_NODE
        {
        // node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(...);
        break;
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is useful - but how do I get the original node? All that I have to work with is an HTML string and an offset. How do I go from that to the node that that string position is a part of?

Comment: +1, @Bungle - this is a better approach than maintaing track of indexes, you can use the above to recurse into non `<a>` and `<h1-6>` nodes, and once you reach a text node (nodeType == 3), use the replace() function in String.

Comment: If all you have is the html, you can do:
 var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
 tmp.innerHTML = myHtml;
 iterateDom(tmp);
or the like.

Comment: Aaaahhh, I gotcha. I left out one requirement that's probably critical - I can only link the first matching term that's linked in the block of HTML. It looks like your example iterator function preserves the order of the text nodes, though, so I think this may work after all - I'd just need to store the text nodes in an array, loop through it and test each node with a matching string for its parents (weeding out `<a>` and `<h1-6>`), and then set a flag after finding the first valid match so I don't link another. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [jQuery Highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). It does *almost* what you need, since you need a link, and only the first occurrence of each word. Its [source code](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-3.js) is extremely simple, so it shouldn't be too much work to get it working (Even if you aren't using jQuery it can help you a lot - it doesn't use jQuery internally, only to select DOM elements).

Comment: Thanks, Kobi! I ended up basing my approach on rob's answer, but the jQuery Highlight plugin that you suggested actually gave me some inspiration for the function that wraps the matching terms in `<a>` elements. I appreciate it.